# Config.json shown instead of the setting UI

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I copied the setting page from the [Demo widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/make-widget-configurable.htm) and I try to adjust it to suit my widget. My `config.json` contains the `configText` variable and several others as well. When I open the config window for my widget in `app1`, I see only the config.json contents, not UI as for other widgets. I can edit the JSON code freely.

So far I found no way to use any [more complex debugging options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/187567/12768) or even how to debug the `settings.js` through FireBug (I can debug `Widget.js`, which works), so I can't confirm that the `setting` code is not even loaded, but it doesn't seem to respond to changes in my `setting.js` or `setting.html` files. The files seem to be on their places (config is read from `WABRoot/server/apps/6/configs/MyWidget/config_MyWidget.json` and the widget from `WABRoot/server/widgets/MyWidget/`), though I might have forgotten to check something. The `setting` code is exactly like in the `Demo` widget, except I renamed `baseClass` from `jimu-widget-demo-setting` to `jimu-widget-my-widget-setting`.

What else can I do, and especially, why do I get the json instead of the UI?

I reposted this on the [ESRI support forum](https://geonet.esri.com/message/599995).

Answer (score 1):

I have another app, let's call it `app2`.
In it, my widget's settings returned an error:

> `Create widget setting page error:widget/MyWidget/Widget`

I tried to find out the reason for the different behavior, so I copied the setting code from `app1` to `app2`.

Before, there was an error in `app2` due to failed attempt to copy another widget's settings there (more complex than the `Demo` widget's), and it was corrected by this simplification, so the settings page shows normally now in `app2`.

In `app1`, I still saw the `config.json` until I found that I have the `"hasSettingPage"`, `"hasSettingUIFile"`, `"hasSettingLocale"` and `"hasSettingStyle"` set to **`false`**.
I changed them to **`true`** and the issue is solved.